# What is the use of upgrading pip?

Tags: python, pip

While pip is used to install and upgrade other Python Packages from PyPI, could you help me understand why an upgrade of pip itself is required? I am working on a new python project and shall be using pip to install the dependencies.

However, I am not sure if I need to upgrade pip to latest version (19.1.1) before installing other packages or an upgrade to pip is not required to install other Packages from PyPI.

Also, I am wondering if pip would have difficulty installing other latest packages, if pip itself is not updated to latest version. Please clarify.

Comment: Same reason you update any other software package. What if pip has a security vulnerability? Performance improvement? Feature added?

Comment: why *wouldn't* you want to ensure you have the latest & greatest version of the code, bug fixes, etc.

Comment: You may be interested in [the list of changes in each pip release](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/).

Comment: @DavidZemens Because new code brings new APIs you have to adapt to (do you remember how pip 10 renamed everything to `_internal`?), new bugs, increased slowness.

Comment: pip doesn't have an API, so it's not going to change an API. If you're still salty about pip 10, well, fine. The `_internal` move was announced long before the release was made and there was a beta period too. If someone's still using pip's internals, I'm not interested in spending my free (volunteered) time helping them understand how to use it in a way we told them not to. As for bugs, all software updates can introduce bugs. I know in pip, they're more painful for users. If you find any in pip, do let us know on pip's issue tracker and like any OSS project, contributions are welcome! :)

Comment: BTW, close voters -- this isn't a "too broad" question. It's fairly specific since pip is a special snowflake here, being the package manager. There's more to the answer here than just "because newer code is the latest and greatest". :)

Answer (score 7):

(pip maintainer here)

For the same reasons as any other package on PyPI -- [newer versions of pip contain bug fixes, new features, security improvements/vulnerability patches](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/) -- and more! Sticking to older versions of pip creates more work for everyone in chain of packaging since new enhancements can't be used by packagers and thus, users.

As an example, there are still some users who are on versions of pip that don't support the mechanisms introduced to ease Python 2 to Python 3 transition for users. This is painful for the users (things don't work), maintainers of the packages (code they distributed doesn't work for users) and pip maintainers (we spent the effort to build a mechanism but folks aren't using it). Luckily this is a fairly small fraction of users but I think this example demonstrates how staying on older versions of pip hurts multiple parties, in more ways than one.

Ideally, users should upgrade to the latest version of pip as eagerly as they can. There's a reason pip prints a message telling users to do so! :)

Comment: Upvoted after seeing "pip maintainer here" :) Thanks. Also followed you on GitHub.

Comment: If I have packages that have been installed via an older version of pip, then should I do something after upgrading pip itself to the latest version?

Comment: No, that should not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

as you probably already know, pip is [Python Package Installer](https://www.pypa.io/en/latest/) which helps you to install packages from places like [Python Package Index](https://pypi.org/)

so basically this task of downloading some package with some defined versions, listing all your installed packages into a file so that you can share it with others *"hey do you know i use tensorflow==1.13.0 for my project super-man"* and others; all these mechanism of how it is done needs upgrades and bug-fixes.

> However, I am not sure if I need to upgrade pip to latest version (19.1.1) before installing other packages or an upgrade to pip is not required to install other Packages from PyPi

The Newly added features and Bug-fixes for each version of PIP can be found here: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#release-notes

Only if you feel that these newly added features or bug-fixes is really important for your work/project, you should upgrade to 19.1.1

> Also, I am wondering if pip would have difficulty installing other latest packages, if PIP itself is not updated to latest version

on average it is a good idea to upgrade PIP to its latest versions (if you do not want to bother yourself with every little details)

also, while installing a package use this to make sure you get the version you want: `pip install <package_name>==<version>`

personally, if you want to get a better "feel" of python, go with older versions as you would automatically get more careful about deprecations like [this](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/news/#deprecations-and-removals)

Finally, `conda` is also not a bad option but PIP is always `pip` :)