# Things to do after upgrading pip itself?

Tags: python, pip

To be more specific: If I have packages that have been installed via an older version of pip, then should I do something after upgrading pip itself to the latest version?

Comment: You probably don't need to do anything more. But if you did something unusual then maybe. If you simply did more or less [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15223296/2550406) then you shouldn't have to do anything further

Comment: @lucidbrot So pip won't detect new stuff on those existing packages after upgrading itself? (Sorry, I know nothing about pip)

Comment: I believe, and [this Q&A seems to support this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56499418/what-is-the-use-of-upgrading-pip/56499710), that upgrading `pip` just means you get some bugfixes or new features for `pip`. The packages you actually rely on in your code should already have worked and the only reason you'd have to do something after upgrading pip is if there was a bug in pip that caused you to have issues installing some package that you hope is now fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer myself: No. So don't worry. But the next time you want to install a new package, please run `pip install --upgrade pip` first.